# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java

Запутался в создании пакетов и классов.
Пытаюсь заполнить массив и вывести его на экран.

```
package com.javarush.test;

/**
 * Created by User on 21.07.2015.
 */
public class Solution {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int [] table = new int [10];
        for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
            table[i] = i;
            System.out.println(table[i] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println(table);
    }
}
```

Вот что выдаёт:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javarush.test.Solution
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: структуру проекта можно?

Comment: @Wolkodav добавил в исправление :)

Comment: @Wolkodav и так же добавил Debug параметры

Comment: Нужно вложенные папки делать ЕМНИП, т.е. не одну папку `com.javarush.test` а три, `com/javarush/test`

Comment: @Vesper попробовал. Выдает ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Проверил, все нормально работает. @Farel Покажи структуру папок.

Comment: @Владимир http://pixs.ru/showimage/Struckt3JP_6367133_18109527.jpg

Comment: @Farel сделай проще. http://pixs.ru/showimage/2107201517_7726393_18109810.jpg

Comment: File \New Project \Java \Project Name Выделяешь src, затем комбинация клавиш ALT + Insert, называешь класс. Пишешь. Не нужно кучу папок делать и путаться в них потом.

Comment: @Владимир при создании нового - работает, а при переключении между проектами сбиваются какие-то настройки. В итоге работает проект, который только что создали. А со старыми проектами всегда такую ошибку выдаёт

Comment: @Farel Какая версия IDE Idea?

Comment: @Владимир 14.1.1

Comment: @Farel Пошагово теперь опишите, как вы создаете проект. Опишите наиболее раскрыто.

Comment: @Farel запустите без IDEA, просто создайте файл, например `Solution.java` потом в консоли `javac Solution.java` потом в консоли `java Solution`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом [скриншоте](http://pixs.ru/showimage/Struckt3JP_6367133_18109527.jpg) я увидел, что пакет `test` пустой (нет треугольничка возле `test`).

1. Положите файл с кодом в директорию, соответствующую пакету
   (т.е. `<project_path>/com/javarush/test`).
2. Проверьте, совпадает ли имя файла с названием класса (т.е. файл
   должен называться `Solution.java`).

**P.S.** Так массив на экран Вы не выведите. При `System.out.println(table)` для `table` вызовется метод `Object.toString()`, который для массива выдаст что-то вроде `[I@...` (см. [документацию по `Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)). Используйте `Arrays.toString()` из `java.util.Arrays`.

**P.P.S.** И да, как сказал @Владимир, на первых порах не стоит так заморачиваться со вложенными пакетами (если это, конечно, не требуется в задании). Конечно, работать в пакете по умолчанию не рекомендуется, поэтому, создайте 1 пакет (в вашем случае, `test`) и работайте :)